# Is there a way to teach tesseract for iOS a new font?

Tags: ios, fonts, ocr, tesseract

Im currently using tesseract for iOS using Nolan Brown's [example](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo). It works ok, but I need it to start picking up a new font (which I have in .tff format) which will always be numbers.

I have found questions on StackOverflow about tesseract learning fonts which all point to the google guides on how to teach Tesseract a new font using command line. But I'm already using a compiled copy of the lib from Nolan's example.

How can I teach tesseract a new font? Will I need to recompile the lib for iOS? How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You might try training a new "traineddata" file using these [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3).